# How to allow selecting unavailable swatches in configurable product

Tags: magento, magento2, configurable-product

By default, unavailable attributes in a configurable product are shown as crossed-out, based on the attributes you have selected, and they cannot be selected.

Is it possible to make it so they can be selected, and when selected, the already selected attributes updates as needed so that you have an available configuration selected?

I believe this is a good example of what we want: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1746590-OREG/apple_mbp_14_m2_51_mbp_14_m2p_10c_cpu_16c.html.  If you select 16.2", for example, you'll see how the other attributes change, as 16.2" is not available with the previously selected attributes.

We have tried various configuration and modified code approaches without luck thus far.